# How to specify precompiled template for typeahead when it is used with ember js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, typeahead.js

I am using typeahead js along with Ember. When I initialize typeahead, I can specify a custom template using the Handlebars.compile, but for this I will have to include the complete version of handlebars instead of just the runtime. This is obviously not a desirable consequence. 
If I try to include the precompiled template as in the code below, I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined

error. 
Here is my code -

```
$("input[name='myTypeAhead']").typeahead("destroy").typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true
  },
  {
        name: "prerequisites",
        displayKey: "val",
        source: this.bhObject.ttAdapter(),
        templates: {
              suggestion: Ember.TEMPLATES["suggestions"]
              // suggestion: Handlebars.compile("<p><strong>{{val}}</strong></p>")
        }

   });
```

and my suggestions template has this -

```
<p><strong>{{val}}</strong></p>
```

The whole call stack is as below -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined suggestions.js:9
anonymous suggestions.js:9
(anonymous function) handlebars.js:436
getSuggestionNode typeahead.bundle.js:1116
jQuery.extend.map jquery.js:686
getSuggestionsHtml typeahead.bundle.js:1107
render typeahead.bundle.js:1095
renderIfQueryIsSame typeahead.bundle.js:1146
get typeahead.bundle.js:619
proxy jquery.js:731
update typeahead.bundle.js:1144
updateDataset typeahead.bundle.js:1314
reverseArgs typeahead.bundle.js:34
jQuery.extend.each jquery.js:590
_.each typeahead.bundle.js:32
update typeahead.bundle.js:1312
onQueryChanged typeahead.bundle.js:1461
flush typeahead.bundle.js:792
trigger typeahead.bundle.js:783
checkInputValue typeahead.bundle.js:968
onInput typeahead.bundle.js:929
proxy jquery.js:731
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:4676
elemData.handle jquery.js:4361
```

Could somebody suggest what is the correct way to go about this? 
Thanks.

Comment: you might be loading template files before handlebars runtime...

Comment: @CodeJack If he was doing that, there would be an error thrown as soon as the Ember templates tried to call `Ember.Handelbars.template()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% about this, but I think it's because of the changes that Ember makes to Handlebars. Ember adds functionality to Handlebars to make it better suited for Ember templates. Because of that, normal Handlebars output is different from Ember Handlebars output. My suggestion would be to not use an Ember pre-compiler, but instead just plain Handlebars pre-compiler.